# DRF ignoring permission classes for owner

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I implemented `BasePermission` class in project but when I am going to retrieve logged user with his token it says `You don't have a permission to perform this action`

**permissions.py**

```
class IsLoggedInOrAdmin(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj.user == request.user or request.user.is_staff


class IsAdminUser(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.user and request.user.is_staff

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user and request.user.is_staff
```

and my views file looks like this

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_permissions(self):
        permission_classes = []

        if self.action == 'create':
            permission_classes = [AllowAny]
        elif self.action == 'retrieve' or self.action == 'update' or self.action == 'partial_update':
            permission_classes = [IsLoggedInOrAdmin]
        elif self.action == 'destroy' or self.action == 'list':
            permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]

        return [permission() for permission in permission_classes]
```

here what i have done so far. I created simple user and took token If I send GET request in Postman I am getting a detail error but it works fine with superuser's token but not owner. Where Am I making mistake? Any help please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am noting from [`DRF Official DOC`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)

> The instance-level has_object_permission method will only be called if
>   the view-level has_permission checks have already passed
>    Also note that in order for the instance-level checks to run, the
>   view code should explicitly call .check_object_permissions(request,
>   obj)

I think here you need explicitly called the `check_object_permission` not relaying on `has_permission`.